# How to add a scroll in JMenu or anything that allows the user to navigate through all the elements in the JMenu that exceeds the screen?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am making a notepad program and I wanted to add all the Fonts selection to the JMenu but when the JMenuItems are too many it runs out of space from the screen and I cannot navigate through the fonts below my screen
How do I put a scrollbar in a JMenu or is there anything that I can add to help me navigate through the list of fonts?
The picture below is my JMenu with all the Fonts and below is my notepad frame class

[image: This is my JMenu with all the fonts available added as JMenuItems]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Writter extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextArea textArea;
    JMenuItem openFileItem;
    JMenuItem saveFileItem;
    JMenuItem saveAsFileItem;
    JMenuItem closeFileItem;
    JMenuItem foregroundColorItem;
    JMenuItem backgroundColorItem;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JScrollPane scrollPaneMenu;
    ArrayList<JMenuItem> menuitemsList = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>();
    JMenuItem menuitems;

    File openFile = null;
    JLabel filePathLabel;
    String[] fonts;
    
    Color colorFont;

    Writter() {
        ImageIcon notepadIcon = new ImageIcon("notepadIcon.png");

        fonts = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

        filePathLabel = new JLabel("File Path: " + "Null");
        filePathLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        this.setTitle("Writter App");
        this.setIconImage(notepadIcon.getImage());
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBackground(Color.black);
        menuBar.setBorderPainted(false);

        JPanel panelMenu = new JPanel();
        panelMenu.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelMenu.setBackground(Color.black);
        panelMenu.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelMenu.add(filePathLabel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu optionMenu = new JMenu("Option");
        JMenu fontsMenu = new JMenu("Fonts");
        //
        fileMenu.setForeground(Color.white);
        optionMenu.setForeground(Color.white);
        fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        optionMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(optionMenu);
        optionMenu.add(fontsMenu);

        openFileItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        saveFileItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        saveAsFileItem = new JMenuItem("Save As");
        closeFileItem = new JMenuItem("Close");
        foregroundColorItem = new JMenuItem("Set Font Color");
        backgroundColorItem = new JMenuItem("Set Background Color");
        for (int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
            fontsMenu.add(menuitems = new JMenuItem(fonts[i]));
            menuitems.setFont(new Font(fonts[i], Font.PLAIN, 15));
            menuitems.addActionListener(this);
            menuitemsList.add(menuitems);
        }
        openFileItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        saveFileItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        saveAsFileItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        closeFileItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        foregroundColorItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        backgroundColorItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        openFileItem.addActionListener(this);
        saveFileItem.addActionListener(this);
        saveAsFileItem.addActionListener(this);
        closeFileItem.addActionListener(this);
        foregroundColorItem.addActionListener(this);
        backgroundColorItem.addActionListener(this);
        fileMenu.add(openFileItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveFileItem);
        fileMenu.add(saveAsFileItem);
        fileMenu.add(closeFileItem);
        optionMenu.add(foregroundColorItem);
        optionMenu.add(backgroundColorItem);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 550));
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        
        this.add(panelMenu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(scrollPane);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == openFileItem) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop"));
            int response = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                textArea.setText("");
                openFile = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                filePathLabel.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                Scanner inputFile = null;
                try {
                    inputFile = new Scanner(openFile);
                    while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                        String text = inputFile.nextLine() + "\n";
                        textArea.append(text);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    inputFile.close();
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == saveFileItem) {
            if (openFile == null) {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop"));
                int response = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
                if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    PrintWriter outputFile;
                    try {
                        outputFile = new PrintWriter(file);
                        outputFile.println(textArea.getText());
                        outputFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                PrintWriter outputFile;
                try {
                    outputFile = new PrintWriter(openFile);
                    outputFile.println(textArea.getText());
                    outputFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource() == saveAsFileItem) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text File (*.txt)", "txt"));
            fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/Users/User/Desktop"));
            int response = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                PrintWriter outputFile;
                try {
                    outputFile = new PrintWriter(file);
                    outputFile.println(textArea.getText());
                    outputFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == closeFileItem) {
            this.dispose();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == foregroundColorItem) {
            new JColorChooser();
            colorFont = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Set Font Color", Color.black);
            textArea.setForeground(colorFont);
        }

        if (e.getSource() == backgroundColorItem) {
            new JColorChooser();
            Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "Set Background Color", Color.black);
            textArea.setBackground(color);
        }
        
        if(e.getSource() == menuitems) {
            System.out.println(menuitems.getText());
        }
        
        for(int i=0; i<fonts.length; i++) {
            if(e.getSource()==menuitemsList.get(i)) {
                textArea.setFont(new Font(menuitemsList.get(i).getText(), Font.PLAIN, 20));
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: UI design advice:  Don’t make a menu with that many items.  Instead, have a single menu item (for example, “Change font…”) which displays a dialog containing a JComboBox or JList with font names in it.

Comment: Maybe you can use the [Menu Scroller](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/01/menu-scroller/)

Comment: A tip for next time (code is probably irrelevant to this problem - I agree with @VGR's approach of 'don't use a menu'): It should take less than 30 lines of code to load all the font names into a menu and show it on-screen. And that's in a [more], as opposed to the > 200 LOC included above that still has no `main` method.

Comment: *"And that's in a [more], as opposed to .."* -> *"And that's in a [mre], as opposed to .."*